# Ansible playbook to list kubernetes pods with ip

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am trying to write get Kubernetes pods with IP using ansible script/playbook. 
I followed the instruction from Ansible documentation where they have shown following example

```
name: Get a list of all pods from any namespace
  k8s_facts:
    kind: Pod
  register: pod_list
```

But this is returning list without ip and node name.

Using kubectl it is possible to get ip and name detail by running following command :

```
kubectl get pods --output=wide --namespace=mynamespace
```

If I have to implement this what should I modify? Meanwhile, I tried passing "output" parameter but the result didn't change (no ip and name listed in the result)

Comment: It does not seem you can specify wide output for the module

Comment: The module [returns everything from the API](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.8.5/lib/ansible/module_utils/k8s/common.py#L224-L227), which on my local test certainly included `{"status":{"hostIP": "", "podIP": ""}}` -- where are you looking in the `pod_list` structure? Have you tried `- debug: var=pod_list` to look at all the resulting data?

Answer (score 0):

I just did:

```
sudo kubectl get nodes -o wide | grep md | grep Ready | awk '{print $6}'
```

With the shell module, and save that output in a file.

I also try to find a module for that, but either way, this works.